# Что означает запись в ячейке Excel: 5,5E-10?

Tags: excel, запись, формулы

Что означает запись в ячейке А1 в excel?
В ячейке A1 написано 5,5E-10
Как на вопрос ответить?

Comment: На вопрос ответить так: запись означает число 0.00000000055. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

1. Что у тебя русская локализация и вместо точки запятая.
2. `E` - экспоненциальная форма записи.
3. `-10` - степень десятки.

```
5.5e-10
5.5 * 10^(-10)
0.00000000055
```

Comment: п.1 не всегда верен :)

Comment: @vikttur, ну да, не только русская. Но явно не английская.

Comment: Нет, я о том, что значение могло быть текстом. А тексту все равно, какой в нем разделитель.

Comment: @vikttur, ну это было бы странно...

Comment: Ничего странного. Такие фокусы встречал (см. мой ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Несомненно, это экспоненциальная запись числа *0,00000000055*.

Как увидеть число в обычной записи?

1. Выделить ячейку и посмотреть значени в строке формул.
2. Расширить столбец до отображения всего числа в ячейке.

Это может не сработать, если в ячейке не число, но текст. Значение могло папасть в ячейку в текстовой записи из сторонней программы или записано в таком виде в ячейку с текстовым форматом.

Эксперимент.

Копируем слово *5,5E-10*  из стартового сообщения, вставляем как значение в ячейку с текстовым форматом (например, в *A2*). В другой ячейке пишем формулу:

```
=ЕЧИСЛО(A2)
```

Формула покажет *ЛОЖЬ*, т.е. в ячейке не число. В строке формул отображается то же значение, что и в тексте сообщения. Это - текст.

Попробуем преобразовать текст в число.

Копируем пустую ячейку, выделяем *A2*, *Спецвставка-Сложить-ОК*.
После этих действий результат формулы *ЕЧИСЛО(A2)=ИСТИНА*. В строке формул тоже можно увидеть число в обычной записи.

Comment: Приведённый способ (вставка, сложить) работает только если разделитель дробной части - запятая. Если точка, то не работает (ячейка остаётся пустой)

Comment: Да, конечно, спасибо за уточнение. Только не пустой - там все также будет текст

Comment: Ой.. Я просто копировал ячейку с этим значением в пустую, а надо было наоборот. Если пустую копировать, то да, текст остаётся.

Comment: Кстати, и с "чужим" разделителем текст можно преобразовать в число, предварительно заменив разделитель на родной: вручную; если значений много - инструмент *НАЙТИ/ЗАМЕНИТЬ*; формулой, макросом... Но, похоже, вопрос из зачета и предполагался ответ об экспоненциальной форме записи )

Comment: Да нормальный вопрос. Запятая как разделить часто в тупик ставит...

Comment: Кстати, если уж вручную, то эксель сам сделает число при нажатии enter (после F2). По крайней мере, если у ячейки явно не задан текстовый формат.